# How access capacitor dependencies in subproject that will be bundled into capacitors webDir

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, node-modules, capacitor

I am having a project that is mainly developed for the web platform. Now we are introducing mobile ports via capacitor. The problem is, the project itself does not live in the capacitor `src` folder, and has a separate `package.json` and is webpacked into a dist folder.

Here is the project layout

```
/package.json                   // main project
/node_modules                   // main projects dependencies
/src                            // main projects code
/webpack.js                     // webpack configuration to create a /dist folder
/platform/Native                // root folder of capacitor
/platform/Native/package.json   // capacitor project
/platform/Native/node_modules   // capacitor dependencies
```

Upon `npx cap sync` capacitor takes the `/dist` folder as `webDir` and bundles it to the native platforms.

The situation happens now when integrating Sentry for capacitor.

- I do not want to add the capacitor Sentry dependency to the root projects
- so the dependency is in `/platform/Native/package.json`

**How can I access the `/platform/Native/package.json` capacitor dependency in the `/package.json` root project?
Are there some types I can refer to in my `/src/*` code that then later will be injected into my main distribution?
How is the projects with such a project layout?**